# How create table with stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to create a stored procedure on SQL Server.

My code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pcreate]
    @name NVARCHAR(50),
    @namefood NVARCHAR(50),
    @restaurantname NVARCHAR(50),
    @pricefood FLOAT,
    @address NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@name]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
        [@namefood] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        [@restaurantname] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        [@pricefood] FLOAT NOT NULL, 
        [@address] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )
END
```

In C# code:

```
db.Pcreate(name.Text, restaurantbox.SelectedItem.ToString(), getEdit1(), float.Parse(getEdit2()), adrresstxt.Text);
```

but the code creates the table with `@name` like in this screenshot:

[image: Example]

Comment: You need dynamic SQL: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl Anyway  table per restaurant is not best idea.

Comment: That image is implying you want your fields to start with the character `@`. I doubt that is your intent. What are you actually trying to do here? *Also, address has 2 d's and 1 r. ;)*

Comment: I want to create restaurant program that a user has table with all foods that he buys and this table create when a user sign up in program

Comment: Never set up tables by user. The correct design is a user table with all the users and then a restaurant table with all the restaurants, then a userRestaurant table that defines the many to many relationship. If you are designing databases, you need to stop right now and read about relational design before going any further.

Comment: I couldn't possibly agree with @HLGEM more. This design is just awful. The last thing you want is a column with the name of the restaurant and another column with the name of the food. This is not well normalized and will do nothing but cause you to want to stab yourself in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Dynamic SQL Using Query String and Execute.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pcreate]
    @name NVARCHAR(50),
    @namefood NVARCHAR(50),
    @restaurantname NVARCHAR(50),
    @pricefood NVARCHAR(50),--Changed from Float Since It's the Column Name
    @address NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    IF OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].['+@name+']'') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].['+@name+']
        (
            [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
            ['+@namefood+'] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
            ['+@restaurantname+'] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
            ['+@pricefood+'] FLOAT NOT NULL, 
            ['+@address+'] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        )
    END
    '

    EXEC(@Sql)

END
```

Comment: While this will technically work it is perpetuating the absolutely horrific "design" the OP is using. The whole concept of this table design is mortally flawed.

Comment: Do not consider doing this unless you read and understand the risks in this article. It is extremely bad to use dynamic SQL unless you are an expert. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Voted down for suggesting dynamic SQL to someone clearly not experienced enough to use it without danger. There are times when it is inappropriate to blindly give the answer and this is one of them.